# Json output SQL query

Tags: php, json

[image: SQl table]

How do I get the output in JSON as follows:

```
"food": {
        "categories": [{
            "cat_id": 122,
            "cat_name": "bear",
            "items": [{
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "abc",
                "isFav": false,
                "price": 12233.555
            }, {
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "abc",
                "isFav": false,
                "price": 12233.555
            }]
        }, {
            "cat_id": 122,
            "cat_name": "bear",
            "items": [{
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "abc",
                "isFav": false,
                "price": 12233.555
            }, {
                "item_id": 1,
                "item_name": "abc",
                "isFav": false,
                "price": 12233.555
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: use `json_decode();`

Comment: That json doesn't match the data in your database, so I am not sure what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to make a 2 dimensional array. Loop through each row, creating an array called `items`. At the beginning of each iteration, check if the current row's `food_cat_id` is different from the previous row's. If it is, push the category onto the result array.

Your last step is to use the `json_encode` function to encode the PHP array as a JSON string.

```
<?php

// I'm assuming you have fetched the rows from database as associative array and saved it as $rows

$categories = [];
$items = [];
$current_cat_id;
$current_cat_name;

foreach($rows as $row){
  // Check if we have moved onto a new category
  if($row['food_cat_id'] != $current_cat_id && isset($current_cat_id)){
    $category = array(
      "cat_id"    => $current_cat_id,
      "cat_name"  => $current_cat_name,
      "items"     => $items
    );
    array_push($categories, $category);
    $items = []; // Reset $items
  }

  // Add the item to the current items list
  $item = array(
    "item_id"     => $row['food_id'],
    "item_name"   => $row['food_name'],
    "isFav"       => $row['food_fav'],
    "price"       => $row['food_price']
  );
  array_push($items, $item);

  // Remember this category id and name for next iteration
  $current_cat_id = $row['food_cat_id'];
  $current_cat_name = $row['food_cat_name'];
}

// Add the last category on after the loop
$category = array(
  "cat_id"    => $current_cat_id,
  "cat_name"  => $current_cat_name,
  "items"     => $items
);
array_push($categories, $category);

$food = json_encode($categories);
```